# Deleting everything, except for two files

Tags: bash, rm, extglob

I would like to delete everything in a folder, including folders, except for two files. To do so, why using this script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

shopt -s extglob
rm !(file1|file2)
```

Which works, but when i try to execute within a case:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

read -r -p "Do you want remove everything \
[y/N]: " response
case $response in
  [yY][eE][sS]|[yY])
      shopt -s extglob
      rm !(file1|file2)
      ;;
  *)
      printf "Aborting"
      ;;
esac
```

This will happen:

```
test.sh: line 9: syntax error near unexpected token `('
test.sh: line 9: `rm !(file1|file2)'
```

I would like to know why this, and more important, how to fix :)

Comment: Replace your first line by full path to bash binary and use option `-i`, e.g. `#!/bin/bash -i`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep `shopt` at start of script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

shopt -s extglob
read -r -p "Do you want remove everything [y/N]: " response

case $response in
  [yY][eE][sS]|[yY])
      echo rm !(list.txt|file2)
      ;;
  *)
      printf "Aborting"
      ;;
esac
```

Comment: Could you explain why?

Comment: Changing `shopt` doesn't work from inside the `case` statement. It only works when placed just before `case`

Answer (score 1):

You can do it this simple way.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# Here you can insert the confirmation part.

f1=file1
f2=file2

mv "$f1" "/tmp/${f1}$$"    #move f1 to /tmp
mv "$f2" "/tmp/${f2}$$"    #move f2 to /tmp

rm -r ./* #remove everything there is. -r means recursive.

mv "/tmp/${f1}$$" "${f1}"    #move f1 and f2 back
mv "/tmp/${f2}$$" "${f2}"
```

It's very simple, so the script has to be run from the directory in question.

Comment: Good stuff. Thanks.